# Dúvida sobre métodos

Tags: c#, método, syntax-error

estou aprendendo pelo livro Use a Cabeça e nele há o seguinte código pra fazer um exercício de itens randômicos

```
   public class Menu
        {
        public Random Randomico;
        string[] Carnes = { "Rosbife", "Salame", "Peru", "Presunto", "Pastrami" };
        string[] Condimentos = { "Mostarda amarela", "Mostarda Marrom", "Mostarda com mel", "Maionese", "Molho Francês", "Gosto" };
        string[] Paes = { "Centeio", "Branco", "Trigo", "Pão italiano", "Pão integral", "árabe" };
    }

    public string ItemMenu() {

        string ramdonCarne = Carnes[Randomizer.Next(Carnes.Lenght)];
        string ramdonCondimento = Condimentos[Randomizer.Next(Condimentos.Lenght)];
        string ramdonPao = Paes[Randomizer.Next(Paes.Lenght)];
        return ramdonCarne + "com " + ramdonCondimento + "no " + ramdonPao;
    }
```

Porém, no Visual Studio, está dando erro na hora da criação do método ItemMenu, mas no livro não se informa nada sobre algo incomum que possa acontecer.

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Menu {
    private static Random randomico = new Random();
    private static string[] Carnes = { "Rosbife", "Salame", "Peru", "Presunto", "Pastrami" };
    private static string[] Condimentos = { "Mostarda amarela", "Mostarda Marrom", "Mostarda com mel", "Maionese", "Molho Francês", "Gosto" };
    private static string[] Paes = { "Centeio", "Branco", "Trigo", "Pão italiano", "Pão integral", "árabe" };

    public string Item() {
        string ramdonCarne = Carnes[randomico.Next(Carnes.Lenght)];
        string ramdonCondimento = Condimentos[randomico.Next(Condimentos.Lenght)];
        string ramdonPao = Paes[randomico.Next(Paes.Lenght)];
        return ramdonCarne + " com " + ramdonCondimento + " no " + ramdonPao;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ClassMethod.cs).

O método precisa estar dentro da classe. Este é o principal erro. Mas também o uso de randômico estava errado, faltava inicializar e usar o nome da variável correta.

Será que precisa fazer assim? Não sei se é orientação do livro ou não entendeu bem o que deveria fazer, mas o código é um pouco estranho.

Comment: Você está certo, cara. Arrumei aqui e ficou certinho. 

O principal problema é que estou seguindo uma apostila em inglês e traduzindo ao mesmo tempo, por isso o nome de algumas variáveis estão erradas, pois esqueço de traduzir.

Mas o principal erro foi eu ter deixado o método fora da classe.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, Maniero.

Valeu mesmo!